# Sort a datasource combobox?

Tags: .net, vb.net

I list folders in my combobox but I'm trying to sort the folders alphabetically and then numerically or vice versa.

My coding to populate my combobox is

```
With Combobox1.DataSource = 
    (From folder In New IO.DirectoryInfo("Path").GetDirectories
     Select (folder.Name)
    ).ToArray
End With
```

Is it possible to sort the combobox? thanks

Hi thanks to both of you for your help but it hasn't really resolved my problem because I have folders that are numbered like 1, 50, 115, 189 etc.

These should display as

```
1
50
115
189
```

however they display as

```
1
115
189
50
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are just an inch to the right syntax

```
Combobox1.DataSource =  
    ( From folder In New DirectoryInfo("Path").GetDirectories()
      Order By folder.Name 
      Select folder.Name 
    ).ToArray()
```

or if you prefer the full qualified path change `Name` with `FullName`

EDIT: Quick fix for your request.

```
    Combobox1.DataSource =  
     ( From folder In New DirectoryInfo("path").GetDirectories()       
      Order By ("00000000" + folder.Name).SubString(folder.Name.Length, 8)        
      Select folder.Name
     ).ToArray()
```

In the `order by` I prepend to the folder name eight `0` chars and then pass the last eight chars to the sort. This should be enough for folders up to "99999999", not tested if you have mixed names in your 'path'

Answer (score 2):

Sure

```
Combobox1.DataSource = 
    ( From folder In IO.Directory.GetDirectories("Path")
      Order By folder
      Select folder
    ).ToArray()
```

Also use `IO.Directory` which provides static methods. It returns the directory names as string instead of a `DirectoryInfo` class. `DirectoryInfo` is better when you have to perform several operations on the same directory.

Also, I don't see what the `With`-statement is doing here.

Comment: Doesn't work. "Name is not a member of string", meaning that GetDirectories return string not DirectoryInfo

Comment: @Steve: You are right. I changed my example (just dropped `.Name`).

Comment: +1 That's was my first try, then I choose to correct the method used by the OP because seems that he needs some other (unclear) sort order and the DirectoryInfo approach gives more options

Comment: @Steve: +1. Yes `DirectoryInfo` gives you more options.